# Select rows of a bool column with false or null values

Tags: postgresql, flutter, supabase, supabase-database

How to filter a database selection, for rows in the table 'notes' and the column 'archived', where the value is null or false? 'archived' is of type bool. I searched Stackoverflow, tried some CodeAI and read the Supabase documentation (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/or), but I didn't find the answer.

Here are my code tests so far:

```
  Future<List<Cost>> getUnArchivedCosts() async {
    final dataCost = await supabaseInstance
        .from('notes') 
        .select<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>()
        // .is_('archived', null); // works 
        // .is_('archived', false); // works 

        // .eq('archived', 'false'); // works
        // .eq('archived', 'null'); // works not
        // .or('archived.is_.false,archived.is_.null'); // works not

        // .not('archived', 'eq', 'true'); // works not really, as the null rows are ignored
        // .not('archived', 'is_', 'true'); // works not
        .or('archived.eq.false,archived.eq.null'); // works not
```

It also seems to me that the Supabase documentation is a bit wrong, as the method ".isFilter" (as shown in the documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/is), is replaced in the code by ".is_".

Comment: Try the Coalesce function: `coalesce(archived,false)` will deliver a false whether archived is false or null.  This is what you do in Postgresql, which is the underlying database in Supabase.  How you actually invoke that function in Supabase, I don't know.

Comment: BTW, you are using the v1 fo supabase_flutter and viewing the v2 of the supabase_flutter docs. `is_` was renamed to `isFilter` in v2, and you can view the v1 docs with the dropdown at the top left.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this will work:

```
.filter('archived', 'not.is', 'true')
```

What I do there is using the operators provided by PostgreSQL (https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html#logical-operators).